# Almacenar cookie tras login en Node.js

Tags: nodejs, express, backend, next.js

Estoy realizando un proyecto con Next.js, Express y React.
Tengo un problema realizando el login de mi página, la función login se encuentra en mi controllers/usersControllers y establezco aquí la cookie:

```
 const token = jwt.sign({ userId: user._id , admin: user.admin}, process.env.JWT_SECRET)

    res
    .cookie("access_token", token, {
      httpOnly: true,
      maxAge: 3600000,
      secure: false,  
      sameSite: 'lax',  
      path: '/'
    })

    return res.status(200).json( { userId: user._id, username: user._username});
```

La función de login funciona correctamente ya que lo verifico con el return de debajo y me logea correctamente. La cosa es que quiero una función verifyAdmin, para verificar antes de hacer algunas cosas que el usuario tenga los permisos necesarios (por eso esta coookie también).

```
exports.verifyAdmin = (req, res, next) => {
    const { access_token }  = req.cookies;
    console.log("Access_token => " + access_token) 
    // if(!accessToken) return res.status(401).json( { message : 'Acceso no autorizado'});
    if(!access_token) return console.log(req.cookies);
    
    try{
        const decodedToken = jwt.verify(access_token, process.env.JWT_SECRET);
        const userId = decodedToken.userId;
        const isAdmin = decodedToken.admin; 

        if(!isAdmin){
            return res.status(403).json( { message : 'Acceso prohibido'})
        }

        next();
    }catch ( error ){
        return res.status(401).json( { message: 'Acceso no autorizado'})
    }
}
```

Esta función la estoy usando cuando llamo a getAllUsers que devuelve todos los usuarios, simplemente para probar, primero llamo a verifyAdmin y luego a getAllUsers, la cosa es que nunca me llega a verifyAdmin un req.cookies.access_token, no existe.
La cookie si se establece en el navegador ya que si voy a red, cojo la petición del login puedo comprobar que está añadida:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

EXTRAS: mi front está en localhost:3000 y el servidor en localhost:5000, tengo añadido cookie parser en mi server.js, cors con las opciones credentials true y origin true , y también estoy usando withCredentials en la petición a la api en el front.

Cualquier idea o sugerencia la aprecio, muchas gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finalmente el problema estaba en que en la solicitud del login era necesario pasar el parámetro

```
withCredentials: true
```

Es algo específico de axios, que es lo que estoy usando para crear el login, igualmente se pueden hacer según he investigado con interceptors para evitar este problema.

https://axios-http.com/docs/interceptors

Answer (score 0):

El problema parece estar en la forma en que estás accediendo a la cookie en la función **verifyAdmin**. Hay un error tipográfico en la línea donde intentas acceder a la cookie:

```
const { acess_token } = req.cookies;
```

Debería ser access_token en lugar de acess_token. La línea corregida debería verse así:

```
const { access_token } = req.cookies;
```

Comment: Solucionado ese error tipográfico sigo obteniendo el mismo error, access_token sigue siendo undefined, y si quiero ver qué hay dentro de req.cookies me muestra una cookie =>  PHPSESSID: 'seriedecaracteres' que no sé cuál es pero no es el token que yo necesito

Comment: estas usando express?

Comment: Sí , te adjunto algunas configs de mi server.js ```//Middlewares
app.use(cors({ credentials: true, origin: true }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.json());

const usersRoute = require("./backend/routes/users");

app.use("/auth", usersRoute);


app.listen(port, () => {
    connect();
    console.log(`Server is running on port ${port}`);
});
 ```

Comment: Parece indicar que el problema podría estar relacionado con la configuración o el manejo de cookies en tu aplicación.
que version de next estas usando?

Comment: Estoy utilizando la última, Next 13.4.2